# Expectation of nonlinear sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

We know that

$$\mathbb E[X^2 + Y^2 + 2XY] = \mathbb E[(X+Y)^2] \quad (1)$$

Obviously the function  $g(X,Y) = (X+Y)^2$ is not linear. However, I have seen that $(1)$ is equal to $$\mathbb E[X^2] +\mathbb  E[Y^2] + 2\mathbb E[XY] \quad (2)$$

But we know that $\mathbb E[g(x,y)] = g(\mathbb E[x,y])$ only if $g$ is linear.
For example if $g(X,Y) =X+Y$, then $\mathbb E[X+Y] = \mathbb E[X] +\mathbb  E[Y]$ because $X+Y$ is linear.
So why does $(2)$ hold?

Comment: What do you want to say with $g(E[x,y])$? Is it the application of g to the sum of X and Y or just another thing?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit.

Comment: The expectation operator is linear, but we don't have that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}^2[X]$. (In general)

Answer (score 1):

$E[g(x,y)]\neq g(E[x,y])$ as $g(E[x,y])=E^2[x]+E^2[Y]+2E[x]E[y]\neq E[x^2]+E[y^2]+2E[xy]$, due to the fact that in general $E^2[x]\neq E[x^2]$.

The reason that 2 hold is that the mean operator is linear in the sense that $E[\sum_ia_if_i(X_i)=\sum_ia_iE[f_i(X_i)]$, where $f_i$ refers to some functions of random variables.

Comment: So the operator E is linear regardless of whether the function is linear or not? Linearity is retained always?

 $$ E[X^2+Y^2] = E[X^2] + E[Y^2]  + 2 E[XY] $$ is true regardless of the fact that $$X^2 + Y^2 $$ is not a linear function?

Comment: Exactly. The linearity of the expectation does not have to do with the linearity of the function applied to the random variables.

Comment: @spyimp: $E[X^2+Y^2] \not = E[X^2] + E[Y^2]  + 2 E[XY]$, unless $E[XY]=0$. In general you can say $E[X^2+Y^2] = E[X^2] + E[Y^2] $ and $E[(X+Y)^2] = E[X^2] + E[Y^2]  + 2 E[XY]$ are true

Answer (score 0):

Note this is is *not* a claim that: $\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) = g(\mathsf E(X), \mathsf E(Y))$ or such.

Expectation is a linear operator, which means that for **any** random variables $U, V, W$ and constants $a,b,c$ then: $$~\mathsf E(aU+bV+cW) ~=~ a~\mathsf E(U)+b~\mathsf E(V)+c~\mathsf E(W)~$$

So with appropriate substitutions, $U=X^2$, *et cetera* we have:

$$~\mathsf E(X^2+Y^2+2XY) ~=~ \mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(Y^2)+2~\mathsf E(XY)~$$

That is all that is happening here.